# Building a pipeline using Microsoft MSBuild publishing targets?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, web-deployment, publish-profiles, msbuild-wpp

I am trying to create a `Build Pipeline`.  I am curious whether I am able to leverage the existing Microsoft publishing msbuild targets or whether I need to write my own from scratch.

I have a large web **site** project (not web application).

The build pipeline is as follows:

1. Checkin Occurs
2. `CI` triggers build called `01 Commit Stage`
3. `01 Commit Stage` automatically triggers `02 Prepare for deployment`
4. `02 Prepare for deployment` automatically triggers `03 UAT`

Here is what I want to happen at each stage:

- **01 Commit Stage**

  - All project files are built
  - Unit Tests are run
  - The website is run through the AspNet_Compiler
- **02 Prepare for deployment**

  - *Output from previous build is used*
  - Output is then run through AspNet_Merge.exe to merge the compiled dlls into a single versioned assembly.
  - Store output artifacts as deployable
- **03 UAT**

  - The artifacts from the previous step are deployed to QA for testing.

My Question is:

`In the second build, how do I skip the build target and simply point the existing Microsoft publishing pipeline to the existing output?  Or would I just be better building my own set of MSBuild targets to do exactly what I need?`

So far, I have had most joy with building my own pipeline, but can't help feel that I am missing out on some MS goodness.

Comment: You didn't mention what build process you're using. Is it the default build template of TFS? An MSBuild script? Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: I am talking about the standard msbuild publish pipeline (Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets).  The version of TFS is not relevant.

Comment: The version of TFS is very relevant as you would never build a release pipeline in MSBuild unless you have to. In 2005/2008 you have no choice but to endure the suffering that is MSBuild. In 2010/2012 you can use Windows Workflow and the out-of-box LabDefaultBuild to deploy to either Hyper-V or Standard environments. In 2013 MSFT have added a built in Release pipeline with approvals and validation steps.

Comment: I think including step 3 in the question has caused confusion - the question is not about deployment or releasing..  My question still exists with or without the new TFS 2013 release management stuff.  My question is: In step 2 - How can I point the existing Microsoft MSBuild pipeline to some previously built artifacts thereby skipping the `build` target?  The reason for this is that I want the `01 Commit Stage` build to be very fast and provide quick feedback of unit tests.  I then want another build to do all the packaging etc preparing for deployment. Reason: AspNetMerge takes 10 mins.

Comment: Again I would recommend that you NOT do this as part of MSBuild. MSBuild is designed for one things and one things only... compiling code. It has been augmented over the years with other bolt on features but that does not mean that it should be used for other things.. I recommend that you switch to Windows Workflow for your orchestration. Oh... and move from a Web Site to a Web Application. Most of your issues will disappear...

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Please forget that I mentioned deploying in Step 3.  I am purely talking about building.  Step 1 is compiling code and Step 2 is effectively AspNetMerging code.  This question has nothing to do with deployment.  I am asking whether I can point the MSBuild pipeline to a set of pre-built artifacts rather than rebuilding it all again in the second step.  I am effectively splitting the build step into 2 parts. The motivation for this is to get a fast feedback loop on CI.  Also converting to WebApp is not practical either, build takes 5 mins in v fast machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TFS 2013 you can use the built in release management tooling to define environments, servers and components to deploy. You then get full traceability, approvals and scheduling of deployments for binary promotion through environments.

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/release-management-vs.aspx

if however you are using TFS 2012 you may need a little more help as there is no release Management tools out if he box. You can however use the Workflow based build system with the LabDefaultTemplate to do deploy and test to environments. If you don't want to do that i would recommend using OctopusDeploy instead.

http://nakedalm.com/release-management-with-team-foundation-server-2012/

If you are in TFS 2005/2008 then you are pretty stuck. The only support would be using the pain and suffering that is MSBuild to do deployment or go to third party tools. To be honest, in this position and due to the age of the product i would recommend upgrading to 2012 and then 2013. Use the latest tools... You can still use VS.old to build and create, but you get the new orchestration and tools.

Comment: Thanks for this.  In the comment above I explain why this doesn't quite answer my question, but it's all very useful insights. The TFS 2013 part will certainly be useful when I get onto the Release Management side of it (we use 2012 currently).  I have tried OctopusDeploy but sadly the NuGet packing takes over 40 mins for my site.  That makes it a no-go.  I have reached out to them a few times on twitter about this, but sadly am yet to get a response. Due to the size of the site, I think I am facing some extra issues which complicates it.

Comment: How big is your site? If you have a lot of media it should maybe be on a CDN?

Comment: The site is very big, but sadly it is deployed to many sites.  It is often used internally only and therefore a CDN is not possible.  Also,  most of the content is code, so again CDN would not help.  Like I said, we are not your usual shop, with 1 production site etc.